# Draw rotated sine image

Tags: c#, image, math, graphics

I'm working with 2D Fourier transforms, and I have a method that will output the following result:
[image: Original Image]

The code looks like this:

```
    private Bitmap PaintSin(int s, int n)
    {
        Data = new int[Width, Height];
        Bitmap buffer = new Bitmap(Width, Height);

        double inner = (2 * Math.PI * s) / n;
        BitmapData originalData = buffer.LockBits(
           new Rectangle(0, 0, buffer.Width, buffer.Height),
           ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < buffer.Height; j++)
            {
                double val;
                int c = 0;

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    val = Math.Sin(inner * i);
                    val += 1;
                    val *= 128;
                    val = val > 255 ? 255 : val;
                    c = (int)val;

                    Color col = Color.FromArgb(c, c, c);
                    SetPixel(originalData, i, j, col);
                }
                else
                    SetPixel(originalData, i, j, GetColor(originalData, i, 0));

                Data[i, j] = c;
            }
        }
        buffer.UnlockBits(originalData);

        return buffer;
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to think of a formula that will accept an angle and will out put an image where the solid lines are at the given angle.

For example, if I inputted 45 Degrees, the result would be:

[image: Rotated image]

Thank you for any help!

Here is the SetPixel code if that is needed:

```
    private unsafe void SetPixel(BitmapData originalData, int x, int y, Color color)
    {
        //set the number of bytes per pixel
        int pixelSize = 3;

        //get the data from the original image
        byte* oRow = (byte*)originalData.Scan0 + (y * originalData.Stride);

        //set the new image's pixel to the grayscale version
        oRow[x * pixelSize] = color.B; //B
        oRow[x * pixelSize + 1] = color.G; //G
        oRow[x * pixelSize + 2] = color.R; //R
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible by using a rotated coordinate system. Transformation of `i` and `j` is as following:

```
x = i * cos(angle) - j * sin(angle);
y = j * cos(angle) + i * sin(angle);
```

Note: I'm not sure about degree/radians here, so adjust `angle` so it fits to the unit that cos and sin do need. Also, you might have to negate the angle depending on your desired rotation direction.

In fact, you only need `x` which replaces your use of `i`. We'll precompute `sin(angle)` and `cos(angle)` because these are quite costy operations we don't want in inner loops. Additionaly, your optimization is removed as we can't draw only one line and repeat it:

```
    [...]
    // double angle = ...
    double cos_angle = cos(angle);
    double sin_angle = sin(angle);
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.Height; j++)
        {
            double val;
            double x;
            int c = 0;

            x = i * cos_angle - j * sin_angle;
            val = Math.Sin(inner * x);
            val += 1;
            val *= 128;
            val = val > 255 ? 255 : val;
            c = (int)val;

            Color col = Color.FromArgb(c, c, c);
            SetPixel(originalData, i, j, col);

            Data[i, j] = c;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's right on! Thanks :) the result is pretty trippy when set to refresh every 50ms....

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple function rotate(x,y,angle) and use its result in SetPixel. You can google for rotation matrix.
A call with angle = 0, should produce default output.